# Removing # and random number from url

Tags: php, html

I am using [AddThis widget](http://addthis.com/) for adding social media buttons on the site but there is a problem with it when we put their code in website it added # and random number in the url which is absolutely not good. So i want to remove it, what can i do? Remember when i print the full url using php code it cannot print this # and random numbers it only prints the exact url which i want.

The url after adding addthis widget lookk like that:

```
http://www.quotewebster.com/topics/193/#.UdFgKNLrzQI
```

But i want it in that way

```
http://www.quotewebster.com/topics/193/
```

Please help me in this case.

Thanks

Comment: you want to change the url that the *widget* produces? You'll have to tamper with the widget if you don't like the way the produced url looks!

Comment: You cannot affect anything after the hash (#), because that part of the url does not get sent to the server whatsoever. You need to modify the source of these links, not the way they are handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `addthis_config` variable, set `data_track_addressbar` to false.

```
var addthis_config = {
    data_track_addressbar: false 
};
```

You can read more about the configuration and the purpose of this hash fragment [here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381254-address-bar-sharing-analytics#.UdFjIWSAnC4).